# What to do in python to create list method of object of a class in next class

Tags: python, list, class, inheritance

I was trying to create class method, a list of next class object.

```
class main:
    a=[]
    def __init__(self):
        self.a.append(1)
        self.a.append(1)
class sub:
    b=[]
    def __init__(self):
        self.b.append(main())
        self.b.append(main())
obj=sub()
print(len(obj.b[0].a))
```

Shows output of `4`

Should not the output be `2` as I am appending two values in `a[]` each time?

Add: Got to know why it shows output `4` instead of `2` but I am trying to create separate list `a[]` for every time constructor is called. i.e. someways output shall be 2.

Comment: The answer is right there in the question: `I am appending two values in a[] each time` (note the **each time**)

Comment: What i mean to have are two different instances a[] in each b[0] and b[1]

Comment: Did you mean: `def __init__(self): self.a = []; ...`?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. That totally worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `obj = sub()` it initializes and `self.b.append(main())` runs twice since it's written twice. Each time `main()` is initialized it appends 1 to `a` twice, that's why it has a length of 4

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful while using **mutable** objects as **class attributes**.
**Class** attributes will be **shared** by all of its objects.

If the class attribute is [**immutable**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/)(int, float, bool, string, unicode, tuple etc) then there is no problem because if an object tries to update it then it will create a new object itself as **immutable** objects cannot be updated.

But if [**mutable**](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747) (list, dict, set etc) is used it will update the original memory address. This causes the problem.

Here's a demo:

**1.mutable class attribute**

```
class mutable():
    lst = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst.append(1)
        print('id:', id(self.lst))


obj1 = mutable()
obj2 = mutable()
obj3 = mutable()

print("list contains:", obj3.lst)


>>> id(mutable.lst)
2377975176712
>>> obj1 = mutable()
id: 2377975176712
>>> obj2 = mutable()
id: 2377975176712
>>> obj3 = mutable()
id: 2377975176712
>>>
>>> print("list contains:", obj3.lst)
list contains: [1, 1, 1]
```

**2. immutable class attribute**

```
class immutable():
    const = 10
    def __init__(self):
        pass

obj1 = immutable()
obj2 = immutable()


>>> obj1.const
10
>>> id(obj1.const)
140718539904096
>>>
>>> obj2 = immutable()
>>> obj2.const = 1
>>> obj2.const
1
>>> id(obj2.const)
140718539903808
>>> obj1.const
10
>>> obj2.const
```

(id prints memory location)

So in your code:
the same list  **a** will be updated at every **init** call and appends 1 twice. And 2 objects of `main()` are initialized hence the content of `a` will be [1, 1, 1, 1].